# --with-arch-32 =?

Tags: gcc, configuration, cpu-architecture

I tried to build the gcc 4.8 trunk on ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit).

When I use the configuration

```
../gcc-trunk/configure -v --with-pkgversion='ubuntu12.04-64' --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
```

I get the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/fenv.h:58:0,
                 from ../../../../gcc-trunk/libquadmath/math/ccoshq.c:23:
../../../../gcc-trunk/libquadmath/math/ccoshq.c: In function ‘ccoshq’:
/usr/include/bits/fenv.h:116:4: error: impossible constraint in ‘asm’
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("divss %0, %0 " : : "x" (__f));
    ^
/usr/include/bits/fenv.h:116:4: error: impossible constraint in ‘asm’
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("divss %0, %0 " : : "x" (__f));
```

But after I delete "--with-arch-32=i686", things are alright.
My cpu is Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU Q9400.
So, what should I use with the "--with-arch-32" option?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraint `x` means an SSE registter. The architecture `i686` does not implement SSE insns. The oldest you can use is `pentium3`.

It depends on where do you intend to run the binaries, generated from this compiler. If it's only for your own use you can configure simply with `core2`.

Comment: I have another question: do you know the difference between --with-arch-32 and --with-arch-64?

Comment: Check install docs http://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html . It sets the default arch when compiling 64-bit code.

Comment: On gcc 4.8.1 the --with-arch=x86-64 options don't seem to work. Use  **-mavx**